# How to get Callback for Google Tag Manager in ios?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-tag-manager

After implementing all the details provided in https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/

I am loging Firebase events as

```
Analytics.logEvent("VCviewDidLoad", parameters: nil)
```

I am getting this in console

```
GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: _vs with parameters: {
    "_o" = auto;
    "_sc" = ViewController;
    "_si" = "-7993663584647244480";
}
```

I want to store this data and forward it to server.And I have no idea how to do it. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed. For others going through the same kind of issues make sure following points, 
1) Your container name is your class name. 
2) You are using the latest published container in your app. 
3) If you are testing it on Simulator, delete the existing app and try again.

Comment: I don't see the output that you see on the console. I've followed all the steps as per the docs. What do you mean by Your container name is your class name - can you share an example ?