# Implementing and Verifying Google Tag Manager Custom Function in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have an iOS app in which I've integrated the Firebase SDK and I can see some basic events firing on the Firebase debug console as expected.

Next, I want to integrate Google Tag Manager(GTM) and I followed this [step by step guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/ios/v5) to integrate Google Tag Manager into an iOS project which suggests to use Firebase Analytics to send events to Google Tag Manager.

The challenge I'm currently facing is two fold:

1. I've followed all the steps in the documentation but how can I verify that GTM console has been configured correctly and I've integrated everything properly ? The preview for mobile apps has such limited documentation and I don't see any logs in the Xcode console related to GTM.
2. I'm trying to implement something called custom function calls for which the [documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/ios/v5/advanced-config)

This is my setup on the GTM console [image: GTM Custom Function Calls iOS Swift] which I got from this [article](https://adswerve.com/blog/getting-started-with-google-tag-manager-function-call-variables-in-app-analytics/)

But again, I don't see any logs or even the function getting invoked, this is my code:

```
@objc
class AnalyticsVariableProvider: NSObject, TAGCustomFunction {
    @objc
    func execute(withParameters parameters: [AnyHashable: Any]!) -> NSObject! {
        guard let parameters else {
            print("no parameters")
            return nil
        }
        
        print("reached")
        print(parameters)
        
        return nil
    }
    
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at some of these other SO threads:

1. [GTM - iOS Custom Tag is not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061703/gtm-ios-custom-tag-is-not-triggered)
2. [How to get Callback for Google Tag Manager in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516676/how-to-get-callback-for-google-tag-manager-in-ios)
3. [Using GTM v5 TAGCustomFunction in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938637/using-gtm-v5-tagcustomfunction-in-swift?rq=3)

But so far none of these helps me.